# Restriction of quotient map $q:X \rightarrow Y$, where $X$ is compact and $Y$ is Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology

Let $q:X \rightarrow Y$ be a quotient map, where $X$ is compact and $Y$ is Hausdorff. Find a subset $A$ of $X$, and a quotient map $q$ and spaces $X$ and $Y$ as above such that the restriction map $q|_A: A\to q(A)$ is NOT a quotient map.

Comment: Not possible in general. If $X=Y$ is compact and Hausdorff, then $q=\mathrm{id}$ is a quotient map, and any restriction of this $q$ is also a quotient map.

Comment: I fixed my question.

Comment: @karen: Since you are new, I want to give some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself. Also, some may consider your post rude because it is a command ("Find"), so please consider rewriting it.

Comment: My problem is that the attempted fix was put in hastily, without care. You can take a few minutes to fix it properly without causing problems. If it will take substantial consideration to fix (not the case here), you can delete the question, then undelete it once you figure out how to fix it.

Comment: it is fixed.  dont understand

Comment: Karen: Technically @dfeuer is sort of correct: the wording of the first sentence says that we’re given an arbitrary quotient map from a compact space to a Hausdorff and suggests that we’ll be asked to prove some general result about this setting. The second sentence then contradicts that by asking for a specific example. It is certainly important that you learn to express yourself more clearly, but I think it perfectly obvious what question you’re asking. I also think that only Zev has been at all helpful, and that the votes to close the question are unwarranted.

Answer (score 6):

Let $X=[0,1]\times[0,1]$ with the usual topology, let $Y=[0,1]$ with the usual topology, and let

$$q:X\to Y:\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto x\;.$$

Let $A=\big([0,1)\times\{0\}\big)\cup\{\langle 1,1\rangle\}$.

- Show that $q$ is a quotient map.
- Show that $q\upharpoonright A$ is not a quotient map. HINT: Consider the set $\{1\}\subseteq q[A]$.

Answer (score 3):

Another example: Let $X=[0,1]\times[0,1]$ with the usual topology. Let $Y=X/B$, the space obtained by collapsing the lower edge $B:=[0,1]\times\{0\}$ to a point, and $q:X\to Y$ the quotient map. Let $A=[0,1]\times(0,1]\ \cup\ \{(1,0)\}$.

- Show that $Y$ is Hausdorff.
- Show that $q|_A:A\to q(A)$ is not a quotient map. Hint: Find an open saturated set in $A$ which is not the intersection of $A$ with an open saturated set in $X$.

If you want $A$ to be open, you can take $[0,1]\times(0,1]\ \cup\ \left(\frac12,1\right]\times\{0\}$. Would a closed $A$ also work?